# How to get back a lost session in RHEL : Using NoMachine

Tags: linux, rhel, nx

I logged in remotely to RHEL using NoMachine. Suddenly it got stuck and I have to close the NoMachine client. When I logged in again using NoMachine I can't see the old session (I can't see same application opened in desktop) Now I want to get it back so that I can close all the application.

One more thing, since Eclipse workspace is opened in the lost session I cannot open the same workspace from another session.

How can I:

A. Either get the lost session(interactive).
 B. Or close the eclipse from different session.

Note: Just to clarify, NoMachine is a remote desktop tool. I use it to connect with RHEL from Windows laptop.

Comment: I don't know NoMachine, but I think that you can just kill your Eclipse process (`ps -ef|grep -i eclipse`).

Comment: 1. About NoMachine- I updated the question. 2. Wont this command kill the eclipse in all the session?

Comment: Not actually, it will kill only the process with the PID you give. And, btw, you should see only one Eclipse process, unless you are running more than one, of course :)
Feel free to add the `ps` to the informations.